# Export a GnuPG private key with a different passphrase?

Tags: gpg

What is the best way to export a private key from a GnuPG keychain, such that the exported key would be encrypted with a different passphrase than the one it's protected by in the keychain?

Ideally, I'd like at most one request for the old passphrase and at most one request (plus verification) for the new passphrase.